# Linking from public website to intranet: are staff an audience?

Tags: intranet, audience

We get a lot of requests to link to our intranet from our public website. For example, the media releases section has a link to the intranet page for the media management team, basically so they can easily find their internal site.

Do you think this is acceptable? The intranet is a bin fire, but I'm reluctant to solve its navigation problems by adding intranet links to the public site.

The argument I've had with people is that staff are also an audience of the website, and so they should be able to access links.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on certain IT or information security policy of your organisation to start with? Assuming this is acceptable, you can work out how to manage access to this by designing the appropriate interactions for it.

Comment: Hi @Anthony, I would encourage you to use the upvote button first and give it a little bit of time before accepting an answer to encourage the community to contribute answers. Just a tip and a show of appreciation for your contribution to the community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues to consider with this question, and depending on the type of organisation there are usually different approaches or philosophies regarding how the information is managed.

The common scenario is to treat the public facing website and the intranet as two completely different buckets of information. This creates the least amount of dependencies (e.g. information architecture, visual design, etc.) but also the greatest potential for doubling up on cost and effort to maintain.

The opposite approach is to have an open and transparent way of presenting the same information so that the public sees what the staff sees, although this is not always appropriate to do so (e.g. if there are privacy or security risks involved with the sensitivity of the information), but it means that there is consistency in the way information is structured and presented which will result in the greatest efficiency.

In general most organisations will need to strike a balance somewhere between the two extremes. One factor you can use as an input to the decision making process is to work out what proportion of the staff within the organisation will also need (or want) to see both the public website and intranet. If it is only a small section of the staff needing to do this infrequently, then the case of creating a feature just for a small set of use cases must be weighed against the potential benefit given the time and cost required to implement such a feature.